# How to create date to date search query in laravel

Tags: laravel

i try to create data search query in laravel. but my script not working. This code works for me but I can't search for specific date to date.

my controller code

```
    function mamla_search_data(Request $data){

    $mamla_number = $data->mamla_number;
    $date1 = $data->date1;
    $date2 = $data->date2;

    if(!empty($mamla_number)){
        $search[0] = ['mamla_number', 'like', '%'.$mamla_number.'%'];
    }

    if(!empty($date1) && !empty($date2)){
        $search[2] =['input_date', '>=', '%'.$date1.'%'];
        $search[3] =['input_date', '<=', '%'.$date2.'%'];
    }

    if(isset($search)){
        $mamla_data = DB::table('mamla_info')->
        where('mamla_status', 'active')->
        where('mamla_input_status', 'complete')->
        where($search)->
        get();
        $search_count = $mamla_data->count();
        return view('search_view.mamla_search',
                    compact(
                        'mamla_data',
                        'data',
                        'search_count'
                    ));
    }
    else{return view('search_view.mamla_search');}
}
```

Comment: use a where stratement for the dates... but remove '%'. and .'%' They are not needed to check your dates

Comment: Working now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function mamla_search_data(Request $data){
$mamla_number = $data->mamla_number;
$date1 = $data->date1;
$date2 = $data->date2;

if(!empty($mamla_number)){
    $search[0] = ['mamla_number', 'like', '%'.$mamla_number.'%'];
}

if(!empty($date1) && !empty($date2)){
    $search[2] =['input_date', '>=', $date1];
    $search[3] =['input_date', '<=', $date2];
}

if(isset($search)){
    $mamla_data = DB::table('mamla_info')->
    where('mamla_status', 'active')->
    where('mamla_input_status', 'complete')->
    where($search)->
    get();
    $search_count = $mamla_data->count();
    return view('search_view.mamla_search',
                compact(
                    'mamla_data',
                    'data',
                    'search_count'
                ));
}
else{return view('search_view.mamla_search');}
```

}